# How to get absolute path of the file selected as input file in python?

Tags: python

I want the absolute path of the file selected as input file (from file browser in the form) using the python code below:

```
 for attr, document in request.files.iteritems():
        orig_filename = document.filename
        print os.path.abspath(orig_filename)
        mhash = get_hash_for_doc(orig_filename)
```

This prints the path of current working directory along(where the python script is executing) with the 'orig_filename' appended to it, which is the wrong path. I am using python 2.7, flask 0.12 under linux OS.

The requirement is to find the hash value of the file before uploading it to the server to check deduplication. So I need to use the algorithm by passing the file selected for hashing to another function as:

```
def get_hash_for_doc(orig_filename):
    mhash = None
    hash = sha1()#md5()
    with open(mfile, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128 * hash.block_size), b""):
            hash.update(chunk)
    mhash = hash.hexdigest()

    return mhash
```

In this function I want to read file from absolute path of the orig_filename before uploading. Avoided all other code checks here.

Comment: What is `secure_filename`, can't you just use `os.path.abspath(document.filename)` ?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question. What is `requeat.files`? What is `secure_filemame`?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a temp file to simulate this required file then make your process on it

```
import tempfile, os
try:
    fd, tmp = tempfile.mkstemp()
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as out:
        out.write(file.read())
    mhash = get_hash_for_doc(tmp)
finally:
    os.unlink(tmp)
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid! copying it

Comment: for a temp time, I think you can't read it from the request directly, try this if worked, then try to find a fined solution of it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a folder/file.ext, for an input file, simply use 'os.path.abspath' like:

```
savefile = os.path.abspath(Myinputfile)
```

when "Myinputfile" is a variable that contains the relative path and file name. For instance, derived from an argument define by the user.

But if you prefer to have absolute address of the folder, without file name try this:

```
saveloc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(Myinputfile))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to find the absolute path of the selected file.

Comment: >>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("python3.4").resolve()
>>> p
PosixPath('/opt/python3/bin/python3.4')
>>> str(p)
'/opt/python3/bin/python3.4'